# handler of click on radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#radans').on("click",function(event)
            {
                $('#ansform').append("<input type='submit' value='accept answer'>")
            });
        });
</script>
```

And i have several RadioButton with id = "radans" and form with id =  "ansform". 
When i click on first RadioButton handler catches this event,but when i clicked on second,third RadioButton, handler doesn't catch this event. How can i solve this problem?

Update:

```
<form id = "ansform" action=/question method="post">

<p>Answers:</p> 

<input id ="radans" type="radio" name="ansvar" value="0"> yes<br>  

<input id ="radans" type="radio" name="ansvar" value="1"> no<br>
```

Thanks for all. Really i have awful mistake with duplicate ID

Comment: Could you post the matching HTML?

Comment: <form id = "ansform" action=/question method="post">

<p>Answers:</p> 

 <input id ="radans" type="radio" name="ansvar" value="0"> yes<br>  

 <input id ="radans" type="radio" name="ansvar" value="1"> no<br>

Comment: @user3237808 An ID needs to be unique for each element. This is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"And i have several RadioButton with id = "radans""

This is wrong. Id should be unique. You cant have many.

In your example `$('#radans').on` activates only for the first id.

Try to add same class on your Radiobuttons for example

```
<input class ="radans" type="radio" name="ansvar" value="0"> yes<br>  

 <input class ="radans" type="radio" name="ansvar" value="1"> no<br>
```

and then use this code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
    $('.radans').on("click",function(event)
            {
            $('#ansform').append("<input type='submit' value='accept answer'>")

            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be unique id in single page i.e. dont use duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

ID of an element must be unique, use a class attribute instead or id to group similar elements then use class selector to select them

So instead of `<input id="radans" .... />` use `<input class="radans" .... />` then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.radans').on("click", function (event) {
        $('#ansform').append("<input type='submit' value='accept answer'>")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique, therefore only the first element will be matched by jQuery. You should chance the IDs to classes.

```
$('.radans').on('click', function() {
    $('#ansform').append('<input type="submit" value="accept answer">');
});
```